# How to create nested state structure using Ngrx?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm building angular 5 application with Ngrx for state management.

I'm trying to build below state tree, where *'Admin'* is the feature and library is a part of Admin feature. And inside library, we can have multiple libraries and each has it own state.

First, is my below state is correct in-terms of normalization. I was trying to build the state as I have my application structure.
So, I thought it would be easy to see the state tree as well in the same way.

Now I created reducers for each Library. And, if I create LibraryReducer Map, I could point to each of the library reducers. But, when I am building admin reducer map, I could n't build it as it requires library to have reducer function (ActionReducerMap). I thought of passing this library reducer Map to AdminReducer, but it is not accepting.

Do you know how to deal with this nested state structure?. If the state tree I'm trying to build is correct, how to work around the error I am facing with ngrx.?

**State Tree:**

```
{
    UIState: {
        ..
    },
    AdminState: {
        LibraryState: {
            Library1: {},
            Library2: {}
        }
    }
}
```

**library.reducer.ts**

```
LibraryState{
    library1: Library1State,
    library2: Library2State,
}

reducer: ActionReducerMap<LibraryState> = {
    library1: library1Reducer;
    library2: library2Reducer;
}
```

**Admin.reducer.ts**

```
AdminState {
    library: LibraryState
}

reducer: ActionReducerMap<AdminState> = {
    library: libraryReducers; // This is error. As ActionReducerMap expects only reducer function not reducer map.
}
```

Comment: You can't use a tree structure with a state store. It creates the problem of parent objects mutating when child objects change. We can't answer the question because your model structure is highly mutable.

Comment: So can you suggest a better structure ?

Comment: You have to keep the data structure flat and avoid nested properties. You can have nested properties, but avoid mutating them independently from the parent object.

Comment: Take a look at ngrx entity: https://ngrx.io/guide/entity

Comment: Thanks. I should keep data in the state as we do in Relational databases instead of trying to keep it like mongo db I guess.